# Merging of two files with substitution

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cat, tac

I need to merge two files, adding the contain of the file 2 directly to the end of the file 1. Notable the last line of the first file consist of the phrase "END". I need to remove it and add there the content of the file 2:

file 1:

```
string 1
string 2
string N
END
```

file 2:

```
string 3
string 4
string M
```

should give me the file 3

```
string 1
string 2
string N
string 3
string 4
string M
```

I've tried simply using

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
```

but it did not substitution of the END in the file2. May I use a special option for this?

Comment: Does the first file always have `END` as the last line? If so, you can use `cat <(head -n -1 file1) file2`

Comment: yes there is always END in the first file, it is like a pattern which should be recognized and substituted by the containts of the file 2. I've jsut tired our sollution but it printed to me only the content of the file 2, so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```sh
sed -e '${r file2' -e ';$d;}' file1

string 1
string 2
string N
string 3
string 4
string M
```

If you want to use `shell` variable instead of file names directly:

```
sed -i.bak -e "\${r $f2" -e ';$d;}' "$f1"
```

Comment: thank you! is it possible to do such modification directly in the file 1 without creating the new file using sed -e '${r file2' -e ';$d;}' file1 >> file3

Comment: @HotJAMS Depends on your `sed` version, but usually you can do `sed -i /^END$/d file1` and it will remove lines containing `END`; IIUC, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @HotJAMS: You can use: `sed -i.bak -e '${r file2' -e ';$d;}' file1` to save changes in `file1`

Comment: if I use this sed inside of my bash script, may I use a bash variable within the sed to indicate the path to the file 2 and file1 ?  sed -i.bak -e '${r "${path_defined_in_my_bash_script}"/file1.pdb' -e ';$d;}' "${path_defined_in_my_bash_script2}"/file2.pqr

Comment: right, thank you! it just did not work directly in the bash environment compared to the awk sollution mentioned below where file 1 and file2 could be directly defined as the variables ..

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `awk`. It !only! skips *END*s occurring on the last line of `file1`. It recognizes the last line of `file1` by using a helper variable `set`.

Test with multiple *END*s in a `file`

```
% awk 'set==""&&NR!=FNR&&last=="END"{last="";set=1} 
    last!=""{print last} 
    {last=$0} END{print}' file file
string 1
string 2
END
string N
string 1
string 2
END
string N
END
```

Using `file1` and `file2`

```
% awk 'set==""&&NR!=FNR&&last=="END"{last="";set=1} 
    last!=""{print last} 
    {last=$0} END{print}' file1 file2
string 1
string 2
string N
string 3
string 4
string M
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
string 1
string 2
END
string N
END

% cat file1
string 1
string 2
string N
END

% cat file2
string 3
string 4
string M
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove last line from `file1` not just the line with `END` value

Comment: @anubhava uh, thanks, gonna adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- `file1` just has the one entry labeled `END`
- the `END` entry is at the end of `file1`

Small modification to OP's current `cat` idea using process substitution to strip the `END` from `file1`:

```
$ cat <(grep -v '^END$' file1) file2 > file3
$ cat file3
string 1
string 2
string N
string 3
string 4
string M
```

---

A variation on Andre's `awk` solution whereby we print everything we see *except* the `file1/END` entry:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR && /^END$/ {next} 1' file1 file2 > file3
$ cat file3
string 1
string 2
string N
string 3
string 4
string M
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU head & cat):

```
head -n-1 file1 | cat - file2 > file3
```

Read all but the last line of file1 and concatenate it with file2.

An alternative:

```
sed -i -e '$r file2' -e '$d' file1
```

This will append file2 to the end of file1 less the last line of file1 and then replace file1 with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 1 more variant of `tac` + `awk` solution here for FUN.

```
tac file1 | awk 'FNR==1{system("tac file2");next} 1' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
tac file1 |               ##using tac command to read contents from bottom to up and sending its standard output as standard input to awk command here.
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
  FNR==1{                 ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
    system("tac file2")   ##Printing file2 bottom to up contents.
    next                  ##next will skip all further contents from here.
  }
  1                       ##Printing rest of lines(passed from tac file1) here.
' | tac                   ##Reversing order again to make it into original order.
```